# How to specify the memory request and limit in kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, memory-management

when creating a Pod with one container. The Container has a memory request of 200 MiB and a memory limit of 400 MiB. Look at configuration file for the creating Pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: memory-demo
  namespace: mem-example
spec:
  containers:
  - name: memory-demo-ctr
    image: polinux/stress
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "200Mi"
      limits:
        memory: "400Mi"
    command: ["stress"]
    args: ["--vm", "1", "--vm-bytes", "150M", "--vm-hang", "1]
```

Above yaml not working as intended, The args section in the configuration file not providing arguments for the Container when it starting.

Tried to create kubernetes pod memory limits & requests & seems fail to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `args: ["--vm", "1", "--vm-bytes", "150M", "--vm-hang", "1"]`. your yaml will work.